# Re-routing request and response to server behind a VPN

Tags: networking, vpn

My situation is as follows: I have a server (A) set up with a VPN connection to a third-party server (B). I have a collection of other servers (C, D, E...) that share the same private network as my VPN-connected server (A).

The third-party server (B) provides a RESTful API that is accessible through HTTP. For instance, from server A I can request some URL:

```
$ curl http://<server-B-vpn-ip-address>/path/to/whatever
```

And I will receive a JSON response with the appropriate data.

I want to be able to access server B's API from any server (C, D, E...) by making a call to server A. For instance:

```
$ curl http://<server-A-private-ip-address>/path/to/whatever
```

Server A should then forward that request to server B, and it should return the JSON response to whichever server initially requested it.

I've looked at a few possible ways to solve this with iptables without success, but honestly I don't know what the right tool for the job is in this case. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this problem by implementing a reverse proxy on server A that modified the request headers before forwarding the request to server B.

Comment: Can you please share more details about the same, I have the same situation, right now even thou the servers are in same network I am passing the request to server b http route on server a, and that isn't very efficient.